# Обновление данных с помощью оператора LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Нужно реализовать добавление и если значения полей одинаковые, замену данных с помощью оператора LOAD DATA INFILE. Пробовал таким способом, но в итоге данные из файла просто добавляются.

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/centos/logs.txt' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE LOGS.access_logs 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

То есть, например, есть таблица:

```
Имя    | Фамилия
Саша   | Александров
Павел  | Сергеев
```

И есть файл с таким содержанием:

```
Саша   | Александров
Павел  | Сергеев
Андрей | Андреев
```

В результате, после выполнении запроса табличка должна стать такой:

```
Имя    | Фамилия
Саша   | Александров
Павел  | Сергеев
Андрей | Андреев
```

Можно ли с помощью `LOAD DATA INFILE` реализовать это? Спасибо.

Comment: RTFM: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как нас учит [RTFM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html), действие модификатора `REPLACE` распространяется *исключительно на встречающиеся дубликаты первичных или уникальных индексов*:

> The REPLACE and IGNORE modifiers control handling of input rows that duplicate existing rows on unique key values:
>   If you specify REPLACE, input rows replace existing rows. In other words, rows that have the same value for a primary key or unique index as an existing row. See Section 13.2.9, “REPLACE Syntax”.

Что в переводе на русский означает:

> Модификаторы REPLACE и IGNORE управляют обработкой входных строк, которые дублируют существующие строки с уникальными значениями ключа:
>   Если вы укажете REPLACE, входные строки заменят существующие. Другими словами, строки, которые имеют то же значение для первичного ключа или уникального индекса, что и существующая строка. См. Раздел 13.2.9, «Синтаксис REPLACE».

`CREATE TABLE` Вы не привели, но исходя из

> Пробовал таким способом, но в итоге данные из файла просто добавляются.

можно заключить, что ни первичного, ни уникального индекса Вы для этой таблицы не построили.